# Object with conditionally optional keys

Tags: typescript

```
function getColors(
    url: string,
    config: Config
  ): Promise<Result>;
}

type Config = {
  dominant?: boolean;
  average?: boolean;
};

type Result = {
  dominant?: string;
  average?: string;
};
```

How can I say if `dominant` was passed as `true` to the config object e.g. `getColors(url, {
dominant: true})` then it is not optional in `Result`.

```
async () => {
  let example : string;

  const colors = await getColors(url, {dominant: true});
  example = colors.dominant;
                 // ^^^^^^ Type 'string | undefined' is not assignable to type 'string'.
                 //        Type 'undefined' is not assignable to type 'string'
};
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

We can do that by [conditional types](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/advanced-types.html#conditional-types). Consider:

```
type Config = {
  dominant?: boolean;
  average?: boolean;
};

type Result = {
  dominant?: string;
  average?: string;
};

declare function getColors<C extends Config>(
    url: string,
    config: C
): Promise<Result & (C['dominant'] extends true ? {dominant: string} : {})>;


async function f() {
  const colors = await getColors('url', { dominant: true })
  colors.dominant // is non-optional string
}
```

The core thing is to have `Config` as generic in `getColors` and append conditional behavior in the return type: `Result & (C['dominant'] extends true ? {dominant: string} : {})`. What we do here is - if `dominant` is true in config, we intersect with our type object having `dominant` required, if `dominant` is false we intersect with `{}` which is neutral element, so we get `Result` back.

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/index.html?ssl=26&ssc=2&pln=1&pc=1#code/FAFwngDgpgBAwgewHYDMCWBzGBeGBvYGGAEwQFs0kBDJEAfgC4YAjBBAGyhoG5CYqAblABOVDFEYs2nHsAC%20vUJFgAlKAGcAruxA58fUhWq1J6kMMoZeRQSLESmZi0ivzFxKAGN2VYbBSaSJ4gaMgw4iCI7AjC6gA8cDBQAB4gUEjE6vDI6BgAfAAUfESawuyO5pYANMUwnjmYTHDAAJRMAArC5GjqUHFqWjowAGQwBXAA2gDkhpQ0IFMAukmp6Zkw5pqwdPizxiAVzhhyMEx4ci15isBU6mBBMAFBIWEoBS36RPVIZnUcMVlcFQAO5UNC6CJRAEFKaldhTKr4EjdfZMTawC58erRWIAOj28xgAHoiTAejAnJYYEgELoEBAXtR2DAIF1oMJwPJgDc7g8nsFQkhHgAmd6fP4-XTYgF6EFgiFQSL-WIwuEIpEE2hMFBUdi9GCYr7K9T4lGEklkrKUlz8DIwemM3UstkicDIozzOjyIA)

Comment: I don't understand that - `colors.dominant` is of type string because it's defined as `string` in the `Result` type, not because of the intersection. If we pass `{dominant: false}`, nothing changes for the types. And the type of `colors` is always `Result & {}`.  Just tried it.

Comment: Its defined as `{dominant?: string}` and not `{dominant: string}`, when we intersect we get `dominant` as not optional. If we intersect with {} we get just the same thing as `Result`. `Result` is equal `Result & {}`

Comment: Added link to the playground with both versions. If we set `false` we get `dominant` optional, if we say `true` dominant is there non-optional.

Comment: OK - found my(!) issue. I tried it on a webstorm scratch file. If I add the code to a regular typescript file, then it works like you said. Probably an IDE bug.

Answer (score 2):

You can provide two signatures by [overloading](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/functions.html#overloads) the function:

```js
interface Config { average?: boolean, dominant?: boolean }
interface ConfigDominant extends Config { dominant: true }

interface Result { average?: string, dominant?: string }
interface ResultDominant extends Result { dominant: string }

// more specific signature must go first
function getColors(url: string, config: ConfigDominant): Promise<ResultDominant>;
// less specific signature
function getColors(url: string, config: Config): Promise<Result>;
// implementation
function getColors(url: string, config: Config): Promise<Result> {
    throw new Error('not implemented');
}

async (url: string) => {
    const colors = await getColors(url, {dominant: true});
    // no error here
    let example: string = colors.dominant;
};
```

[Playground Link](http://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgMIHsQ2Ac2Qb2TgDdo4cIB+ALmQCN10AbCOEAGmQBN0BbUNmBr1GLNsgC+AWABQoSLEQoMWXABE+A8MggAPSCC4BnNJmx5CPfiEG0wUAK4ppM2fOjwkyAEoQjDpjACIlIocipaI3tQHE4rLSFI6JA8F3dFL19-QI1rQR19CEMTLICgy00bcCSoGMlZWQB6RuRedCgUIwAHCARgbARkI1wbMAcO1oco5Bx0ZGwoKNkYBxAEMGBMGYgwDCZ2owAKcaYamM4EM1xaFXNchIBKWgAFKE0jCAAeUpzKwQA+ADcTRaLCMJm6vX6wEGwxwo3GEGWq3WmxA212zAOxygpyGyViyEuqhwNyuOCeyFe7y+PzAQJByGAvC6LF4RTAcA2mGRa256IomP2ixxeKitRSF3JZJJlOp-A+3z8ZX+BFkyA1yDAAAs3gB3ZAgCAGgCiUDeUEOAHIQOggszWRB2eAIFwrQ9gTIXLI4EYAJ5rZCis4pB7IAC8qvw6s1xOml2FJnDRD1cGAQUFe2xJ04+HiVTAdkcEAkHpjGuahrm0AtyG10CRMk1yBYQT0cBZLBDeGTCYOADp84JPRJPUA)